# mkdir(): No such file or directory - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to create a directory but I got this error :

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 390: mkdir(): No such file or directoryErrorException in Filesystem.php line 390: mkdir(): No such file or directory


 in Filesystem.php line 390
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'mkdir(): No such file or directory', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yatan\yatan\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php', '390', array('path' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yatan\yatan\public/assets/images/projects/1/1476592434/', 'mode' => '511', 'recursive' => false, 'force' => false))
```

my code :

```
    $to_main_image = time();
    $path = 'assets/images/projects/'.$user_id.'/'.$to_main_image.'/';
    File::makeDirectory(public_path().'/'.$path,0777);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change the line

```
File::makeDirectory(public_path().'/'.$path,0777);
```

to

```
File::makeDirectory(public_path().'/'.$path,0777,true);
```

So that the sub-directories are also created.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was driving me crazy, the weird thing is that it was working on Windows and the Shared Server, in the Mac Dev machine  fails... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if using laravel 5.8 then try this out

go to vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/KeyCache/DiskKeyCache.php and find prepareCache function and edit line no 247 -

```
if (!mkdir($cacheDir))
```

to

```
if (!mkdir($cacheDir,0777,true))
```

Adding the code snippet as well.

```
private function prepareCache($nsKey)
    {
        $cacheDir = $this->path.'/'.$nsKey;
        if (!is_dir($cacheDir)) {
            if (!mkdir($cacheDir,0777,true)) {
                throw new Swift_IoException('Failed to create cache directory '.$cacheDir);
            }
            $this->keys[$nsKey] = [];
        }
    }
```